# Web.config urlMappings - works for local pages, not remote pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a MVC4/.Net 4 website running on IIS 7.5.  In my web.config file I have the following in my  block:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
 <add url="~/2013calendar" mappedUrl="~/CustomerService/RequestPocketCalendar" />
 <add url="~/teachers" mappedUrl="http://www.somexternalsite.com/teachers/" />
</urlMappings>
```

The local redirects all work great, but anything that is redirecting off the site, such as the /teachers link in the above example return "http://www.somexternalsite.com/teachers"  is not a valid virtual path.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up creating a page to handle external redirects such as follows:

redirect.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = Request.QueryString["page"];
    Response.Redirect("http://"+page);
}
</script>
```

So in my web.config I have external files referenced as such:

```
<add url="~/teachers" mappedUrl="~/redirect.aspx?page=www.somexternalsite.com/teachers/" />
```

Works great!

Comment: Be carefore with this unvalidated method - it's subject to a OWASP "Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards" where a evil party could hook off your redirect.
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html
I'd tend to send codes and confirm with a configured URL in the redirect page as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the mappedUrl field is a path relative to the root of the application.  As such, "http://www.somexternalsite.com/teachers/" is not valid.

If you'd like to configure this to redirect, I would just create a "Teachers" action in your root controller, then use the following:

```
return Redirect("http://www.somexternalsite.com/teachers");
```

Comment: You are correct in it being relative to root... But what do you mean by hard coding it into the list?

Comment: I had assumed this was for something else, didn't look closely :P.  Updated with fix.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you not use a config in the RouteConfig file for <add url="~/2013calendar" mappedUrl="~/CustomerService/RequestPocketCalendar" />?

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to keep all redirects in ONE place, rather than scattered all over the controllers.  Probably not the BEST way to do, but certainly the easiest to maintain for us.