# URL Rewriting for domain names in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, dns, seo

I would redirect site1.com\site2 to site2.com , I am working with asp.net and MVC4, I couldn't do it with changing web.config file , is there any solution? I don't like Search Engine takes this a permanent redirection(Status 302) or (Status 301) and  removes site2 from its database.

Comment: Just to clarify: 301 is permanent redirect (`301 Moved Permanently`), 302 originally temporary redirect (but now *redirection for unspecified reason*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the route "site2" to an action of one of your controllers.

The action  response for that route should be:

```
return RedirectPermanent("http://www.site2.com");
```

Comment: Can we separate redirection from our code? can we do something in web.config? because I have list of redirections like site1.com\site2 and site1.com\site3 to site3.com , ...

Comment: I don't think so. You can extend the routing pipeline but that will be more dificult than map the routes to an ExternalController with all actions. However I found this post that may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457247/web-config-urlmappings-works-for-local-pages-not-remote-pages

Comment: And you can use a Resource File to manage the URL in place of my hard coded example.

Comment: gustavodidomenicoo: Sorry we don't need external resource . now my concern is search engines, because most of times they take this links as status 302.